# How to impute missing value in time series data with the value of the same day and time from the previous week(day) in python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, missing-data

I have a dataframe with columns of timestamp and energy usage. The timestamp is taken for every min of the day i.e., a total of 1440 readings for each day. I have few missing values in the data frame.

I want to impute those missing values with the mean of the same day, same time from the last two or three week. This way if the previous week is also missing, I can use the value for two weeks ago.

Here's a example of the data:

```
                    mains_1
timestamp   
2013-01-03 00:00:00 155.00
2013-01-03 00:01:00 154.00
2013-01-03 00:02:00 NaN
2013-01-03 00:03:00 154.00
2013-01-03 00:04:00 153.00
... ...
2013-04-30 23:55:00 NaN
2013-04-30 23:56:00 182.00
2013-04-30 23:57:00 181.00
2013-04-30 23:58:00 182.00
2013-04-30 23:59:00 182.00
```

Right now I have this line of code:

```
df['mains_1'] = (df
    .groupby((df.index.dayofweek * 24) + (df.index.hour) + (df.index.minute / 60))
    .transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
)
```

So what this does is it uses the average of the usage from the same hour of the day on the whole dataset. I want it to be more precise and use the average of the last two or three weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `concat` together the Series with `shift` in a loop, as the index alignment will ensure it's matching on the previous weeks with the same hour. Then take the `mean` and use `.fillna` to update the original

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2010-01-01 10:00:00', freq='W', periods=10),
                  data = np.random.choice([1,2,3,4, np.NaN], 10),
                  columns=['mains_1'])
#                     mains_1
#2010-01-03 10:00:00      4.0
#2010-01-10 10:00:00      1.0
#2010-01-17 10:00:00      2.0
#2010-01-24 10:00:00      1.0
#2010-01-31 10:00:00      NaN
#2010-02-07 10:00:00      4.0
#2010-02-14 10:00:00      1.0
#2010-02-21 10:00:00      1.0
#2010-02-28 10:00:00      NaN
#2010-03-07 10:00:00      2.0
```

---

#### Code

```
# range(4) for previous 3 weeks. 
df1 = pd.concat([df.shift(periods=x, freq='W') for x in range(4)], axis=1)
#                     mains_1  mains_1  mains_1  mains_1
#2010-01-03 10:00:00      4.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
#2010-01-10 10:00:00      1.0      4.0      NaN      NaN
#2010-01-17 10:00:00      2.0      1.0      4.0      NaN
#2010-01-24 10:00:00      1.0      2.0      1.0      4.0
#2010-01-31 10:00:00      NaN      1.0      2.0      1.0
#2010-02-07 10:00:00      4.0      NaN      1.0      2.0
#2010-02-14 10:00:00      1.0      4.0      NaN      1.0
#2010-02-21 10:00:00      1.0      1.0      4.0      NaN
#2010-02-28 10:00:00      NaN      1.0      1.0      4.0
#2010-03-07 10:00:00      2.0      NaN      1.0      1.0
#2010-03-14 10:00:00      NaN      2.0      NaN      1.0
#2010-03-21 10:00:00      NaN      NaN      2.0      NaN
#2010-03-28 10:00:00      NaN      NaN      NaN      2.0

df['mains_1'] = df['mains_1'].fillna(df1.mean(axis=1))
```

---

```
print(df)

                      mains_1
2010-01-03 10:00:00  4.000000
2010-01-10 10:00:00  1.000000
2010-01-17 10:00:00  2.000000
2010-01-24 10:00:00  1.000000
2010-01-31 10:00:00  1.333333
2010-02-07 10:00:00  4.000000
2010-02-14 10:00:00  1.000000
2010-02-21 10:00:00  1.000000
2010-02-28 10:00:00  2.000000
2010-03-07 10:00:00  2.000000
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I try to concat the series I get this error:
`Shape of passed values is (332640, 4), indices imply (182880, 4)`
Also, does this method takes the minute into account? As I mentioned, my time-series resolution is 1 min.

Comment: @AshkanLotfipoor  It does take the minute and second into account becaue index alignment requires an exact match and we're just adding 7 days to the date, including time. I'm not sure about the error, perhaps you have duplicates which is messing something up?

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. It works great.